# Issue replacing fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

A very weird issue here.

My application contains one main activity and that activity is the "router" for all fragments in my application. This is really the first time I have used fragments intensively in an application.

I have a Nav Drawer containing many links. One of those links contains a ListView (Parent ListView) with a BaseAdapter, when user clicks on an item under that Parent ListView, it takes the user to another ListView (Child ListView). When I try to click on another link under my Nav Drawer from the Child ListView. The application first loads the Parent ListView then it takes the user to where they clicked.

My thought is that I am moving from Parent ListView to Child ListView, and I am not attaching the next fragment (Child ListView) correctly. Below is the code that is in the Parent's ListView BaseAdapter that takes user from Parent to Child ListView.

```
            Fragment newFragment = new SingleCartListView();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("def_cart_id", resultp.get(ViewCartsFragment.DEFCARTID));
            bundle.putString("cart_name", resultp.get(ViewCartsFragment.CARTNAME));
            newFragment.setArguments(bundle);

            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            transaction.commit();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity: when an item in NavDrawer is clicked, remove all the fragments from the stack and then call fragment transaction. Do the following:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.popBackStack();

// now change the fragment
manager.beginTransaction().replace((R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. When I click the NavDrawer item, it still takes the user to previous fragment and then to the one the user clicked on.

Comment: delete the addToBackStack part

Comment: I did and still it is not working. The only thing that even get drawn on the screen is the ProgressDialog from the previous fragment and then it goes to the fragment the user clicked on. It doesn't even draw the entire contents of the screen.